# Angular Material mat-error display error from api

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a form that contains an email, when i save the form i call the onRegisterFormSubmit function, in this function i get the errors returned by the api then i set the error in the email fromcontrol and get the message, in the html i check if the control has an error to display the message, but the message is not displayed in case of error

```
export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
    isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
        const isSubmitted = form && form.submitted;
        return !!(control && control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched || isSubmitted));
    }
}

matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();

this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  'email': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, emailValidator])]
});

public onRegisterFormSubmit(): void {
    if (this.registerForm.valid) {
        this.facade.register(); // save the form
        this.ngrxFormsFacade.errors$.subscribe(error => { // get errors from api
            if (error & error.email) {
                this.registerForm.controls.email.setErrors({ 'emailExist': true });
                this.errorEmailMsg = error.email;
            }
        })
    }
}

<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100 mt-1">
  <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
  <input matInput placeholder="Email" formControlName="email" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" required>
  <mat-error *ngIf="registerForm.controls.email.hasError('emailExist')">{{errorEmailMsg}}</mat-error>
  <mat-error *ngIf="registerForm.controls.email.errors?.required">Email is required</mat-error>
  <mat-error *ngIf="registerForm.controls.email.hasError('invalidEmail')">Invalid email address</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this solution and set the error message as the value for your key **emailExist** and you will not need **errorEmailMsg**

```
this.registerForm.get('email').setErrors({ emailExist: error.email});
```

and the display it like so

```
<mat-error *ngIf="registerForm.get('email').errors?.serverError">
              {{ registerForm.get('email').errors?.serverError }}
</mat-error>
```